# Is there a difference in performance how a linq expression is constructed?

Tags: .net, performance, linq

Is there a difference in performance depending on where the `where` clause is located in a linq expression?

Take a look at the code below:

```
dbContext.AnEntity.Include("AnotherEntity").Where(e => e.ID == id).ToList();

dbContext.AnEntity.Where(e => e.ID == id).Include("AnotherEntity").ToList();
```

Is the execution plan of these two expression the same or do the differ?

Comment: Are you sure your code actually compiled? `Include` is called on an `ObjectQuery<T>` instance, but the `Where(some lambda expression here)` method returns `IQueryable<T>`. I don't think you can choose where to place the `Include` actually.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, no. In reality, you will need to test on a case-by-case basis, and on a provider-by-provider bases. For a related (but slightly different) example, for a good long while in L2S, `.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()` and `.FirstOrDefault(predicate)` (which have the same semantic) did *not* have the same behaviour (in particular relating to identity-map shortcuts).

I *expect* it will be the same, especially since `.Include` (expands the result set) is in a bit of a separate categry than `.Where` (a predicate) but: the only way to verify would be to test it and compare the generated SQL and performance.

Comment: "messen ist wissen" ("to measure is to know")